# SQL count case else 0 vs null

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I really need an explination for this. Say you have the following table:

```
    Columns:
id  int(11) AI PK
user_id int(11)
is_complete int(11)
```

In the above table `is_complete` can either be `1` or `0`

Now you wish to do some counting so you create the following `SQL` statement:

```
COUNT(CASE
    WHEN is_complete = 0 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END) AS not_complete
```

Say the result of this would be:

[image]

(Which is incorrect)

Now you change the exact same statement to:

```
COUNT(CASE
    WHEN is_complete = 0 THEN 1
    ELSE null
END) AS not_complete
```

*Note ive changed `0` to `null`*

And you get the following result:

[image]

After some intense testing you will find that the 1. incorrect statement actually counts all no matter what.

My question is why?

Comment: Because is counting every value that's not a null, that's how it works. And `0` is not null, `1` is not null, and every other value but `NULL` will bie counted. If you want to use `THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` use `SUM` instead of `COUNT`

Comment: So See Sum()...

Comment: why don't you use count(*) from table where is_complete = 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Count ignores nulls, but not any other values. 
I think you where thinking about sum:

```
COUNT(CASE
    WHEN is_complete = 0 THEN 1
    ELSE null
END) AS not_complete
```

Is like

```
SUM(CASE
    WHEN is_complete = 0 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END) AS not_complete
```

Answer (score 1):

The subtlety is because the COUNT statement is counting for the *presence of a value*. NULL causes that row to be eliminated from the COUNT; the first version never returns NULL, hence all rows are included. As a result, the counts are different.

You could perform a summary of all values in the table via:

```
select is_complete,count(*)
  from tablename
 group by is_complete
```